# Issues connecting with MoveIT Freely in Implicit mode: "Security handshake failed"

Tags: ftp, ftps

A vendor we are connecting to using MoveIT has asked us to update our connection from explicit to implicit. We use an automation tool in conjunction with MoveIT to download/upload files from them.

I've changed the connection from explicit to implicit and manually tried to connect but received the error "Security handshake failed", yet when I connect manually with WinSCP in implicit mode I am successful. I am also able to connect to another vendor in explicit mode with no issues so it's something in the connection that I'm missing when connecting in implicit mode.

The connection used to be (when manually connecting):

```
FTPS -a -e:on -s:"script" -z -user:user -password:password ftp.site 2010
```

The new connection was changed to (when manually connecting):

```
FTPS -a -e:implicit -s:"script" -z -user:user -password:password ftp.site 2010
```

The required port is 2010. I've also removed the -z argument to see if any errors were occurring that the argument was suppressing but nothing further than what was already displayed occurred.

There doesn't appear to be a way to generate logs while connecting with MoveIT Freely.

```
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 -------------------------------------------------- 
------------------------
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 WinSCP Version 5.15.1 (Build 9407) (OS 6.1.7601 
Service Pack 1 - Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard)
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 Configuration: E:\Program Files\WinSCP\WinSCP.ini
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 Log level: Normal
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 Local account: xxxx
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 Working directory: E:\Program Files\WinSCP
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 Process ID: 2388
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 Command-line: "E:\Program Files\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" 
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 Time zone: Current: GMT-6, Standard: GMT-7 
(Mountain Standard Time), DST: GMT-6 (Mountain Daylight Time), DST Start: 
3/10/2019, DST End: 11/3/2019
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 Login time: August 09, 2019 12:05:59 PM
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 -------------------------------------------------- 
------------------------
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 Session name: SessionName (Modified site)
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 Host name: XXXXX (Port: 2010)
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 User name: xxxxx (Password: Yes, Key file: No, 
Passphrase: No)
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 Transfer Protocol: FTP
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 Ping type: Dummy, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 
15 sec
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 Disable Nagle: No
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 Proxy: None
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 Send buffer: 262144
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 UTF: Auto
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 FTPS: Implicit TLS/SSL [Client certificate: No]
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 FTP: Passive: Yes [Force IP: Auto]; MLSD: Auto 
[List all: Auto]; HOST: Auto
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 Session reuse: Yes
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 TLS/SSL versions: TLSv1.0-TLSv1.2
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 Local directory: default, Remote directory: home, 
Update: No, Cache: Yes
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 Recycle bin: Delete to: No, Overwritten to: No, 
Bin path: 
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 Timezone offset: 0h 0m
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.848 -------------------------------------------------- 
 ------------------------
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.864 Connecting to xxxxx:2010 ...
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.864 Connected with xxxxx:2010, negotiating TLS 
connection...
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.879 Verifying certificate for "xxxxx." with 
fingerprint e4:95:b2:74:84:83:3f:b7:b9:b5:68:75:c5:df:f4:72:93:1d:70:c0 and 
19 failures
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.879 Certificate common name "xxxxx" matches hostname
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.879 Certificate for "xxxxxx" matches cached 
fingerprint and failures
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.879 Using TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3: AES256-GCM- 
SHA384, 2048 bit RSA, AES256-GCM-SHA384       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  
Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910 TLS connection established. Waiting for welcome 
 message...
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910 220-xxxxx X2 WS_FTP Server 8.0.1(01361057)
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910    This ftp site and all data accessed from this 
site are considered proprietary and are solely intended for 
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910    authorized users only. Use of this site and all 
applications accessed from this site implies you have received proper 
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910    authorization, have agreed to comply with all 
security policies, and are consenting to have all activity monitored.
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910 220 xxxxxxx X2 WS_FTP Server 8.0.1(01361057)
> 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910 USER xxxxx
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910 331 Enter password
> 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910 PASS ********
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910 230 User logged in
> 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910 SYST
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910 215 UNIX
> 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910 FEAT
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910 211-Extensions supported
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910     SIZE
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910     XMD5
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910     XSHA1
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910     XSHA256
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910     XSHA512
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910     XQUOTA
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910     LANG EN, ES, FR, GE
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910     MDTM
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910     MLST size*;type*;perm*;create*;modify*;
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910     REST STREAM
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910     TVFS
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910     UTF8
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910     AUTH SSL;TLS-P;
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910     PBSZ
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910     PROT C;P;
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910 211 end
> 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910 OPTS UTF8 ON
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910 200 Command OPTS succeed
> 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910 PBSZ 0
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910 200 PBSZ=0
> 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910 PROT P
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.910 200 PRIVATE data channel protection level set
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.926 Connected
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.926 --------------------------------------------------        
------------------------
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.926 Using FTP protocol.
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.926 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2019-08-09 12:05:59.942 PWD
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.942 257 "/" is current directory
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.942 Getting current directory name.
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.988 Retrieving directory listing...
> 2019-08-09 12:05:59.988 TYPE A
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.988 200 Transfer mode set to ASCII
> 2019-08-09 12:05:59.988 PASV
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.988 227 Entering Passive Mode (198,161,254,236,7,219).
> 2019-08-09 12:05:59.988 MLSD
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.988 Connecting to 198.161.254.236:2011 ...
< 2019-08-09 12:05:59.988 150 Transferring directory
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.988 Session ID reused
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.988 Using TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3: AES256-GCM-    
SHA384, 2048 bit RSA, AES256-GCM-SHA384       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  
Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
. 2019-08-09 12:05:59.988 TLS connection established
< 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 226 Transfer completed
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 Data connection closed
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472     
size=0;type=cdir;create=20150812082558;modify=20150812082558; .
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472     
size=0;type=pdir;create=20150812082558;modify=20150812082559; ..
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 
size=0;type=dir;create=20150812082558;modify=20160921165245; ab91-inwes001
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 
size=0;type=dir;create=20150812082558;modify=20150812081738; users
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 
size=0;type=dir;create=20080613072531;modify=20190808225416; eroworksftp
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 
size=0;type=dir;create=20090806092745;modify=20190301231156; eroworksftp- 
ewks
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 
size=0;type=dir;create=20131213072011;modify=20190808192101; ewks-cofuploads
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 
size=0;type=dir;create=20160330121521;modify=20160330121521; a553p
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 
size=0;type=dir;create=20160330121234;modify=20160330121234; a548p
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 
size=0;type=dir;create=20160114113714;modify=20160114113714; a553t
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472     
size=0;type=dir;create=20160114113249;modify=20160114113250; a548t
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 
size=0;type=dir;create=20160330121647;modify=20161125100808; A555P
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 
size=0;type=dir;create=20160114114322;modify=20160114114322; a559t
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 
size=0;type=dir;create=20160330121757;modify=20160330121757; a559p
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 Directory listing successful
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 ..;D;0;1899-12-30T07:00:00.000Z;0;"" [0];"" [0];-- 
-------;0
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 ab91-inwes001;D;0;2016-09-21T16:52:45.000Z;3;"" 
[0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 users;D;0;2015-08-12T08:17:38.000Z;3;"" [0];"" 
[0];---------;0
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 eroworksftp;D;0;2019-08-08T22:54:16.000Z;3;"" 
[0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 eroworksftp-ewks;D;0;2019-03-01T23:11:56.000Z;3;""     
[0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 ewks-cofuploads;D;0;2019-08-08T19:21:01.000Z;3;"" 
[0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 a553p;D;0;2016-03-30T12:15:21.000Z;3;"" [0];"" 
[0];---------;0
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 a548p;D;0;2016-03-30T12:12:34.000Z;3;"" [0];"" 
[0];---------;0
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 a553t;D;0;2016-01-14T11:37:14.000Z;3;"" [0];"" 
[0];---------;0
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 a548t;D;0;2016-01-14T11:32:50.000Z;3;"" [0];"" 
[0];---------;0
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 A555P;D;0;2016-11-25T10:08:08.000Z;3;"" [0];"" 
[0];---------;0
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 a559t;D;0;2016-01-14T11:43:22.000Z;3;"" [0];"" 
[0];---------;0
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.472 a559p;D;0;2016-03-30T12:17:57.000Z;3;"" [0];"" 
[0];---------;0
. 2019-08-09 12:06:00.519 Startup conversation with host finished.
```

Comment: Can I post the WinSCP log? I sure can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> . 2019-08-09 12:05:59.988 Session ID reused

The server possibly requires TLS/SSL session reuse. Apparently this is not supported by MOVEit version 8.0 and older. Quoting an old documentation from community.ipswitch.com that was removed meanwhile:

> MOVEit Automation(Central) 8.0 and earlier do not support TLS Session Resumption.
>
> If the host you are connecting to has this implemented on their end, you will see MOVEit Automation(Central) generating a error similar to the following after successfully connecting :
>
> > Error getting directory list from host: 2850 Could not list directory: **Security handshake failed.** Response: 150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/"

So make sure that you have a later version.

---

Or, as WinSCP works for you, you can use WinSCP.

If you are not aware of that, [WinSCP has a scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) too.